# Securing a REST API

Tags: java, php, web-services, rest, oauth

I am in the middle of developing a PHP social media web application which will be supported by various web services each operating a REST API. Web services will probably be implemented in Java with MySQL data layer but the whole point of what I am trying to do is make it really easy to implement modules in different languages/data stores depending on what is approriate.

So for example when the user logs into the application via a login form the PHP code connects to a web service and POSTs the username and password to check if they should be authenticated. I would normally at this point start a session and store it in a session data store.

Another example could be if a user sends a private message to another user. The message would be POSTed to the private messaging web service which would take care of all the storage. Similarly the web service could be contacted to retrieve messages for a user.

Although I understand how to implement the REST web service in Java and make the connection to it in PHP I am totally unsure as to how to secure the data being passed and make sure that it is the users data being returned. If for example I want to get all of user As private messages how does the web service know to return that users. I could pass that users identifier as part of the GET url but then surely any old user could just figure out the GET url and use it to look up other peoples messages. I thought maybe I could pass over the session identifier and IP address which would allow me to check the session data store and make sure it is the correct user?

To secure the data that is important - like the username/password I thought I would just pass it over SSL.

Hope this explains my problem better.

Thanks

Comment: Do you develop a solution for Internet or Intranet? Do you use Microsoft Products (ASP.NET MVC or WFC 3.5/4.0) to create the Service and IIS to host this? Do you want to have authentication or privacy? With more information you could receive a better answer.

Comment: I have added a lot more info in light of Olegs comment. Sorry for the obscurity of the previous question - was written very late at night!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at HTTP Digest authentication. Most clients should support it, and it means the auth details can be passed securely with each request as part of the headers without interfering with the payload of the request itself.

Answer (score 1):

I think requiring OAuth is a good choice.  Your end users should appreciate that other websites don't need to ask usernames and passwords to access their data.  As far as SSL, it's clearly worth doing if you can.  You'll have to see if the performance trade-off is acceptable.

Answer (score 0):

Keep in mind that your api must mimic the HTTP protocol.

Http is stateless, and by adding any Sessions or so, you're trying to fake an "Alwaysconnected" method.

With a LoginForm, it's like I'll have to send two requests for each calls ;)

Comment: So if I have a web application where users are logging in - I would normally create a session which would be stored in a database. My plan here was to use PHP simply as the final part of the page construction. So the web app would make calls to multiple restful web services to get all the data. But depending on who you are logged in as it would depend what data you got back. So I thought you would have to authenticate somehow with the web service so that it knew who you were. Are you saying that because the HTTP protocol is stateless it wouldnt be approriate to use REST for this?

Comment: To my mind, an api must be simple by its implementation, its names ... 
By using Session, you constraint developers to have a cookie mechanism isn't it ?
If you just use HTTP authentication, something useing http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php would probably suffice.

Answer (score -1):

These are basically 2 questions.

When privacy is a concern I'd go for the safest option: Serve data over SSL (via HTTPS).

As far as authentication is concerned, there are several possibilities. Basic over SSL is one of them, but a simple login form with a cookie can be another one. (ASP.Net Forms Authentication for example.) This all depends on how you want to implement your authentication mechanism.

Comment: A login form isn't appropriate for a API.