# nodejs - private REST API

Tags: node.js, angularjs, rest

I have created a simple REST api for my application using node/ express. I am using AngularJS on the front end to serve pages to the user.

I would like to add functionality such that the API can only be accessed via my front-end and anyone should not be able to do a `GET/POST` request to my site and get the data?

What strategies can I use to achieve this?

Comment: Using authentication middleware? [Passport](http://passportjs.org/), for example.

Comment: I couldn't quite understand how to integrate that into my solution as I am don't want to use password etc..

Comment: You don't have to use password etc.; there are different auth strategies.

Comment: Ok did some reading, https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-anonymous looks like this could help me. Am i correct?

Comment: This thread may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496915/how-to-implement-a-secure-rest-api-with-node-js

Comment: Anyone can make exactly the same requests as a browser; you can make it a pain to do so automatically, but this fact will not change.

Answer (score 1):

HTTP request can be formatted and sent to sever by many other means beside a browser (curl for example), so any server always detecting correct source of a request is not guaranteed.

The basic method to protect an endpoint would be to use some kind of authentication. The requesting client must present something uniquely identifying it. API should provide clients a token after it proves itself authentic (via login etc), and all subsequent requests would be checked for this token.

Comment: If my client is a web application written in AngularJS, anyone can view the source and the token, how can I go around that?
Sorry if my questions are amateurish.

Comment: @dopplesoldner That's why you encrypt it and store it in session storage of one user's browser.