# Securing Node.JS APIs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, security, ejs

Now I have read this [Secure node.js restful API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23449387/secure-node-js-restful-api) 
But I need some more detailing.

**Objective**
To call an api from client(js,angular,ejs) to server(node.js) but securely enough that one cannot just tamper with the key:values sent.

**Situation**
I create a `app.post({});` for specific uri and `return res.json();`. Now here is the problem,

The Controller takes one param say id. now id = 1 is Apple, id = 2 is Microsoft.

I return Apple and Microsoft Respectively but I dont want that a visitor(anonymous) can just change to id to 2 and get MIcrosoft's Data.

1. Visitors are anonymous at this point, for non anon users i use sessions.
2. If I keep salt or generate hash then the algorithm will be visible via source code.
3. if I use AUTH then credentials will be visible.

I hope I am clear enough on my problem, will wait for an answer.

**an example code**

```
...
exports.statement = function(req, res){
  dcn_db.pool.getConnection(function(err, connection){
    if(!req.body.opid){
      return res.sendStatus(400);
    }
    var opid = req.body.opid;
    var con = req.body.con;
    connection.query(data_model.mini_statement(req),[opid,con], function(err, rows, fields) {
      if(err)   {
        console.log('Error while performing Query. ' + err); //error respose
        return res.json({ error : "true"})
        }else{
          return res.json({ error : "false", data : rows}); //parse result to json instantly
        }
    });
    connection.release();
  });
};
...
```

The above code takes in opid and con....
opid is main thing here
how would u treat it?

Comment: You can't. It's impossible. Users have the right to throw whatever packets of data they want at your server. It's up to you to perform authorization server-side.

Comment: so what do you suggest? consider that id is the main element should i use id in an encrypted form and decrypt it on server? or something else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot control what goes on outside your server. The user has complete control over what they put in the request.

> I return Apple and Microsoft Respectively but I dont want that a visitor(anonymous) can just change to id to 2 and get MIcrosoft's Data.

Then you need to perform authentication and authorization checks before allowing them access to Microsoft's data.

> Visitors are anonymous at this point, for non anon users i use sessions.

If you have an anonymous visitor then you need to check, on the server, if what has been requested is allowed to be given to anonymous users. If it isn't, you need to reject the request as unauthorised.

> If I keep salt or generate hash then the algorithm will be visible via source code.

That doesn't matter because only authorized users should have the password to put into the hash algorithm. That shouldn't be relevant anyway, you should use HTTPS to secure the data between the client and the server and cryptographic hashes to secure the data for storage in your database of users.

> if I use AUTH then credentials will be visible.

Only to you and the authorised user to whom the credentials belong (assuming you use HTTPS, which you should do).

Comment: point is if i do a ajax request, even https, i can easily go to source code and see exactly what params are passed and what data is provided back

Comment: @RohitHazra — Yes, you can. But that shouldn't be a problem. You aren't going to put anything the user isn't authorised to see in the request in the first place, and if they change the parameters to ask for something they aren't allowed to see then you'll reject the request as being for something unauthorised.

Comment: as of rite now, in the example i provided if i send '1' in opid i will get 1's data and '2' will fetch me 2's data. 
so what do u suggest something like session to store these, but what if the request is via android (i am no android genius) but i guess i can see the url and params

Comment: Put the user's username and password in each request.

Comment: the problem i face is the types of device that access data, there are embedded devices, mobile phones, and WPF Apps other than the website itself

Comment: How is that a problem? You just need to pick a way to accept the credentials for the user and then include the credentials, in that fashion, in each request.

Comment: so wid every request just add a username and password and request it to an https server so it cannot be sniffed?

Comment: Yes. That's a simple, but effective, approach to the problem.

Comment: maybe i was just being paranoid then?

Answer (score 0):

While 1st and 2nd items depends on your architecture, and I don't know why won't you differentiate the auth data to some other space than using all in the same one.

So far the solution for this look rather simple, use **UDIDs** instead of integer IDs in your database(backend).

If you can share an example of the code you have and data you are trying to serve via your API, that will allow us to elaborate more on it.

Thanks.

Comment: Please see, I have added an Example