# Best practices to implement client-server authentication

Tags: node.js, oauth, sails.js, access-token

I'm looking for an best practices to implement client-server authentication (local + social).
Right now I'm developing backend & frontend separately. Earlier I did auth by next flow:

> Sign in -> receive token -> call api

I need find a way to add token into blacklist also.
Tech stack: node.js (sails)
front-end: angular

Also front-end app should be available to call api of multiple servers. That means front-end app should sign in only once at main server and be available to call another api's.

I'm opened for out-of-box solutions.

Comment: There are different questions about this argument on SO ...
Here some of them:

[Link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15496915/how-to-implement-a-secure-rest-api-with-node-js)
and
[Link2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/319530/restful-authentication)

Comment: Did you check passport.js http://passportjs.org/ ? Working example; https://scotch.io/tutorials/easy-node-authentication-setup-and-local

Answer (score 1):

If you are using JSON Web Tokens (JWTs) as your token: you can put a unique, random value as the `jti` claim in the token.  You store these `jti` values in your database and use them as your blacklist.

If you would like to read about JWT best practices for Single Page Apps with APIs, please see a blog post I've written on this topic:  [Token Based Authentication for Single Page Apps](https://stormpath.com/blog/token-auth-spa/)

Regarding out-of-box solutions: I work at [Stormapth](https://stormpath.com) and we have such a solution in our [Stormpath Angular SDK](https://github.com/stormpath/stormpath-sdk-angularjs).